# ¿Cómo funciona y cómo se usa nameof C# VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Cuando ejecuto mi aplicación aparece el siguiente error estoy usando VS 2010:

> The name 'nameof' does not exist in the current context

Comment: ¿El código? @Cromlo agrega más detalles a tu pregunta para evitar sea cerrada, ver [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después de investigar y buscar un poco mas encontré algo que aclaro mis dudas espero les sirva.

nameof es un operador que acompaño a C# a partir de su versión 6
Este devuelve el nombre de una variable  Por ejemplo, para referenciar miembros de instancia hay que hacerlo como si fueran miembros estáticos de la clase donde residen:

[image: Por Ejemplo]
http://www.variablenotfound.com/2014/10/el-operador-nameof-de-c-6.html

creo que en vs2010 ya no esta disponible alguien que me corrija si me equivoco por favor.

Answer (score 2):

`nameof` es un método introducido con C# 6.0. Lo que hace es devolver el nombre de una variable como un string. Por ejemplo:

```
int variable = 0;
string nombreVariable = nameof(variable); //en nombreVariable devuelve "variable"
```

Como digo, este método fue introducido en la versión 6.0 del lenguaje, que corresponde con el .net framework 4.6. Si usas Visual Studio 2010, tu target framework es menor. Aunque es posible usar `nameof` en versiones anteriores, es un tema un poco complicado, asi que o bien actualizas tu Visual Studio a la versión 2015, o puedes crear un método `nameof` en tu código usando `reflection`.